# prerender express-handlebars templates to include them in other templates

Tags: node.js, templates, express, include, handlebars.js

this might not be a question, but an answer I found by myself that I want to share.

I had a dashboard app working with express-handlebars and wanted to put the code of each module in other templates to include them dynamically.

I found a solution by recursively rendering a list of modules while emptying a list of module paths and rendering the html to save into the data object there all templates get their data from.

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    var mainTemplate = 'dashboard';

    var modules = [
        {
            name : 'FIVE_MONTH_OVERVIEW',
            path : 'modules/fivemonth'
        },
        {
            name : 'LAST_CHANGES',
            path : 'modules/lastchanges'
        }
    ];

    var data = {};

    recursiveRender(res, req, modules, data, mainTemplate);
});
```

And the function (req is currently unused, but might be used to read GET/POST parameters and cookies):

```
function recursiveRender(res, req, list, data, final, lastHtml){
    list = list || [];
    data = data || {};
    if(list.length === 0){
        if(final){
            res.render(final, data);
        }
        else if(lastHtml){
            res.send(lastHtml);
        }
        else{
            res.status(409).send('Conflict.');
        }
    }
    else{
        var item = list[0];
        list.splice(0, 1);
        data.modules = data.modules || {};
        data.modules[item.name] = item;
        res.render(item.path, data, function(err, html){
            data.modules[item.name].html = html;
            recursiveRender(res, req, list, data, final, html);
        });
    }
}
```

It might be used to render static html directly:

```
 recursiveRender(res, null, null, null, null, "<html>...</html>");
```

Or render a single template with data:

```
 recursiveRender(res, null, null, data, "dashboard");
```

or

```
 recursiveRender(res, null, [{name: "templatename", path: "templatename"}], data);
```

If anyone says 'that is possible much easier.' - tell me, i'd love to know! :)